# Inserting array objects into a database

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array which am saving to a var $multi...

```
{
"multicast_id":6026270875633827713,
"success":2,
"failure":1,
}
```

This is my current implementation that doesn't work...

```
$bony = "INSERT INTO log_notifications(sent_at,multicast_id,reg_id,message_id,success,failed) 
        VALUES(NOW(),
        '$multi[multicast_id]',
        '$each',
        '$multi[multicast_id]',
        '$multi[success]',
        '$multi[failure]'
        ";
```

I cant seem to insert the values in the db...

Comment: This is not an array this is JSON you need to convert into array.Use `$multi = json_decode($str, true);` to convert into array

Comment: Your array access seems wrong, shouldn't it be e.g. `$multi['failure']` (with quotes around the key)?

Comment: @Saty didn't work....

Comment: After using `$multi = json_decode($str, true)` what is the value of `print_r($multi)`??

Comment: @Saty it outputs 111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$bony = "INSERT INTO log_notifications(sent_at,multicast_id,reg_id,message_id,success,failed) 
    VALUES(NOW(),
    '$multi[multicast_id]',
    '$each',
    '$multi[multicast_id]',
    '$multi[success]',
    '$multi[failure]')";
```

You forgot to close `)` for `VALUES(`;